# Is it possible to calculate $\ell_2$ norm of a sum of matrices based on their largest eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

Let $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix}^T$ where $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Ax=A_1x_1+A_2x_2$. Based on the largest eigenvectors (and their corresponding eigenvalues) $v_i : \frac{\|A_iv_i\|_2}{\|v_i\|_2}=\|A_i\|_2=\lambda_i$ is it possible to calculate $\|A\|_2$?

At first I thought $\|A\|_2=\max(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$, but this is not the case:

$\|A\|_2=\max_w\frac{\|\sum A_iw_i\|_2}{\|w\|_2}=\left(\max_w\frac{\|\sum A_iw_i\|_2^2}{\|w\|_2^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(\max_w\frac{\|\sum A_iw_i\|_2^2}{\sum\|w_i\|_2^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\neq \left(\max_w\frac{\sum\| A_iw_i\|_2^2}{\sum\|w_i\|_2^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Can $\|A\|_2$ be expressed using only $v_1$, $v_2$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$? If not, I am certain at least an upper bound can be calculated, that is $\|A\|_2 \leq (\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$; can a better upper bound be calculated as a function of $v_1$, $v_2$?

The point is to find a formula that does not contain any matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2
\end{bmatrix}$, then

$$\left\|A\right\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(AA^T)} = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}\left(A_1A_1^T + A_2A_2^T\right)}$$

Comment: I see, perhaps this is a clearer way to state the problem. This doesn't explain however whether this can be calculated from the largest eigenvectors of $A_1$ and $A_2$ alone. Can $\lambda_\max(A_1A_1^T+A_2A_2^T)$ be expressed using only $v_1$ and $v_2$? I am still not fully clear on this, but since your answer suggests this cannot be done, I've edited my question to ask about an upper bound if exact formula cannot be found.

Comment: The upper bound that you find is tight and I do not think you can have better than that.